# Import data from a file in a shared folder location to SQL Managed Instance?

Tags: azure, import, azure-sql-managed-instance

I've been trying to import data from a file into a table in SQL Managed Instance. I was able to successfully import data from a text file and an Excel file that I uploaded in a Blob container in Azure Storage to my desired tables in SQL Managed Instance. While that is all good, I already have a structure set up in a shared location and I was wondering whether it is possible to be able to import data from files in that location in my network to SQL Managed Instance or not?

Comment: For Azure SQL database/managed instance, it only support load files from Azure storage.

Comment: Hi @Abdinassir,  If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Abdinassir, haven't heard you for a long time, do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0):

For Azure SQL database/managed instance, it only support load files from Azure storage.

It doesn't support access file from the network or file shares. Ref this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915676-sql-managed-instance/suggestions/37818301-make-managed-sql-instance-able-to-access-azure-fil):
[image]